# using textWatcher for input

Tags: kotlin, uitableview, addition, subtraction, textwatcher

I am working an app that display table inputs and a total,
i am using a text Watcher to keep truck with changes in the edit text
but the issue, when I tried to change inputs the total won't display properly
When I erase the input it should be subtracted with the total and when added a new input it should be added with the total.?

```
var fifthUp = 0  

 floor5_up.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            var a = 0
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                fifthUp -= a
                Log.i("PO TEXT",p0.toString())
                total5F_up.text = fifthUp.toString()
                a = 0
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                Log.i(TAG, " floor5")
                if(p0.toString() != "") {

                    fifthUp += Integer.parseInt(p0.toString())
                    total5F_up.text = fifthUp.toString()
                    a = Integer.parseInt(p0.toString())
                    findValue( floor5_up, 5,2, 16, 0)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you do 2 separate logic in `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged`? As I can see it can be merged and used in 1 callback only, avoid unexpected behavior

Comment: I want it to handle changes with inputs that would display in the total ui when user erase input the erase value should be subtracted in the total and when user added a new value it would add up in the total

Comment: So the total will be changed (increase/decrease) at the same time as the user type, am I right? What if the user wants to type 12, he first types 1 => you add 1 to the total, then he types 2 => you add 2 to total. It will sum up as increase by 3, not 12

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, the total should be changed base on the user inputs, in my case I have multiple inputs so if the user wants to type 12 it should be added with the existing input and display in the total and when user erase the input value of 12 it should be subtracted with the existing input value and the displayed total should be change base on the user input.